# Javascript adjust div position after zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm working on a script where there is an image on a canvas. The user can zoom on the image with the mouse wheel (using d3js zoom), the zoom is centered to the mouse position.

My problem is that i have also some div on the canvas that are supposed to highlight parts of the image. Those div position should be updated when zooming so they still highlight the same spot. But I'am struggling to find a good way to do it. Here's a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrav6gkp/9/) as a basic example, so i want the div to cover the same spot of the image even when zooming.

Code used to zoom the image:

```
function zoom() {
    var e = d3.event;
    var tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[0], 408 - 408 * e.scale));
    var ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(e.translate[1], 464 - 464 * e.scale));
    context.save();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 408, 464);
    zoomE.translate([tx, ty]);
    context.translate(tx, ty);
    context.scale(d3.event.scale, d3.event.scale);
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 408, 464);
    context.restore();
}
```

Thanks.